# realm navigate model inside model inside model and change data

Tags: java, android, kotlin, realm, realm-mobile-platform

say i have model a with id 1,2,3,4,5
a has model b model c model d inside.
the data inside b c d is same in a = 1,2,3,4,5

so what i want is i want to change the value of xyz inside model a where id =1 , insideb , inside c, inside d. please check the image.

when i try to edit the xyz string of a =1 and inside a =1 b c d. only
how do i change the value of xyz of a =1 only.

[image]

Comment: please add your code

Comment: I can't answer this question without seeing real realmModels.